# define a custom style to a ListViewItem in a universal app

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am trying to set this Style to my ListViewItems when the Mouse hover on them:

[image: Example ListViewItems with arrow pointing to emphasized line]

I have modified the Style from the App.xaml file but this doesn't solve my problem

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#d9d7ec" />
```

Then,I did a Style when Mouse hover on it,but this either doesn't work

```
  <Style  x:Key="listItemmenuStyle"
    TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#d9d7ec" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="listItem1" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#393185" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ListViewItem.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#d9d7ec" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="listItem1" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#393185" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ListViewItem.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content1" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="listItem1" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent" Margin="0"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and this is How I apply this Style to the ListView:

```
<ListView Style="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource listItemmenuStyle}}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate >
     <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock x:Name="day" Text="{Binding Path=day}" Foreground="#797978"></TextBlock>
     </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate >
</ListView
```

Please How can I modify the Style to have a ListviewItem like the image above
thanks for help

Update:
I tried this solution,and it changed the Background color of ListViewItem when I hover,but I get always a problem in defining the Foreground Color when I hover on every ListViewItem,even with change of the PointerOverForeground color propeerty:

```
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
<ListViewItemPresenter
   FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="#d9d7ec"
   PlaceholderBackground="#d9d7ec"
   PointerOverBackground="#d9d7ec"
   PointerOverForeground="#342d65"
   SelectedBackground="#d9d7ec"
   SelectedForeground="#d9d7ec"
   SelectedPointerOverBackground="#342d65"
   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
   VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
   Foreground="#342d65"
     />
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>                                                   
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set `Foreground` color same as `PointerOverForeground` color, you can't distinguish the color when you hover on an item. I think you should set different colors for `Foreground` and `PointerOverForeground`. According to your image, maybe `Foreground` should be set to `Gray`:

```xml
 <ListView Name="myList">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <ListViewItemPresenter
                                FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="#d9d7ec"
                                PlaceholderBackground="#d9d7ec"
                                PointerOverBackground="#d9d7ec"
                                PointerOverForeground="#342d65"
                                SelectedBackground="#d9d7ec"
                                SelectedForeground="#342d65"
                                SelectedPointerOverBackground="#d9d7ec"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                Foreground="Gray" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: thanks Sir John Zhang for your reply,what I need is to change the Foreground color to Black per example,I still can't get that with your code

Comment: I have updated my DataTemplate Code if this helps Sir

Comment: I have updated my DataTemplate Code in my Post if this helps Sir

Comment: You have defined ListItem style in `ItemContainerStyle` so you don't need setting the style of `ListView` . Delete `Style="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource listItemmenuStyle}}"` and change `Gray` to `"#797978"` in ItemContainerStyle , you don't need setting `Foreground` in `TextBlock`